# In python requests, what does SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2600) mean?

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I am trying to test SSL two-way authentication. The snippet of Python code causing the error is dang simple:

```
r = requests.get(some_url, cert=(path_to_cert, path_to_private_key), auth=(user_id, password))
```

This produces the error message in the title. What does that mean? Does it mean that I don't have a valid cert?

Comment: This is probably a malformed certificate or key you use here, i.e. not properly PEM encoded.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there are two (or more) ways to create SSL certs. One is to use Java's keytool utility. The second is to use OpenSSL. This python requests code works fine with OpenSSL. I'm not sure what needs to be done differently with keytool-generated certs.